# Vector Rasterize error using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I am attempting to convert vector files to raster format in QGIS using the Rasterize tool and am receiving the error:

> ERROR 1: Wrong value for -tr parameter.

I have attached an image of the input and errors I am getting. And I am using QGIS v 3.2.3.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to set a vertical and horizontal resolution, not leave it at zero.

Comment: But why? If the attribute has no vertical component (e.g. tree density) what meaning does "vertical resolution" have?